# Angular 9: Cannot find namespace 'FullCalendarVDom'?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, rrule

I installed `rrule` plugin by running:

```
npm install @fullcalendar/rrule
```

but when I add its import to my component:

```
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import rrulePlugin from '@fullcalendar/rrule';  //error appears after adding this import
```

I get this errors:

```
    node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/vdom.d.ts:16:28 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FullCalendarVDom'.
    
    16 export import flushToDom = FullCalendarVDom.flushToDom;
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/vdom.d.ts:16:28 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'FullCalendarVDom'.
    
    16 export import flushToDom = FullCalendarVDom.flushToDom;
```

Other plugin imports are working fine.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it's useful for anyone, here's what worked for me.

(Edit: I'm obviously using PrimeNG with Angular...)

In the `xyz.component.html` file:

```
<p-fullCalendar #calendar ...></p-fullCalendar>
```

In the `xyz.component.ts` file:

```
import {FullCalendar} from 'primeng/fullcalendar';

...

@ViewChild('calendar') private calendar: FullCalendar;
```

Didn't need to use the `calendar` field for anything, but this hack seems to get the imports in the right order. For some reason. Go figure.